# Is there exact formula that returns minimal period of a periodic function?

Tags: periodic-functions

Is there exact formula that returns minimal period of a periodic analytic function? For constant it should return 0, for non-periodic functions - infinity.

I only came to the following but it requires taking the smallest branch of a multivalued function. I would like an answer not involving multi-valued functions.

$$T[f]=\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f(s+t)-f(s)|ds\right)^{[-1]}|_{t=0}$$

Comment: Not all functions have a minimal period: Consider the characteristic function $\chi_{\mathbb Q}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ of the rational numbers.

Comment: What is "inexact" in the term "minimal period"?  Why not just use that?  Or will you restrict what you mean by "exact formula"?

Comment: @Travis for such functions the formula ideally would return $0$ like for constants. But I would be satisfied if the formula worked for only analytic functions.

Comment: @GEdgar I want a formula(expression) representation, that would give it for arbitrary analytic function. Like a limit, series, integral, sum etc.

Comment: I suppose what you're looking for is a function that returns the *infimum* of all of the periods.

Comment: @Travis yes, infimum of all positive periods. Ideally. But if it worked only for non-constant analytic functions, it would be ok.